# How to combine media query in scss

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I ried to put comma to combine media query but didnt work

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait),
@media all and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 840px) and (orientation : portrait) {}
```

any ideas how to do that in scss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of @media on the second line:

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait),
all and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 840px) and (orientation : portrait) {}
```

That has nothing to do with SCSS by the way. It is how you declare media queries in plain css too. Here is some documentation, refer to comma-separated lists - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: any ideas on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088294/how-to-add-specific-media-query-rule-when-media-query-combined ?